# How to call a function with dlply argument?

Tags: r, plyr

I wish to write a function using `dlply` to fit a linear regression stratified by

```
"cat1 by arg1"
```

So my function looks like this

```
fun1 <- function(arg1) {
     m1 <- data.frame(...) 
     mod.var <- ...
     mod.form <- formula(paste("y ~", paste(mod.var, collapse = " + ")))
     list_of_models <- dlply(m1, .(cat1,arg1), function(X) lm(mod.form, data = X, 
          na.action=na.omit), .parallel=FALSE) 
}
```

How to write a function so that when I call the function `fun1("cat2")` the function will execute

```
list_of_models <- dlply(m1, .(cat1,cat2), function(X) lm(mod.form, data = X,
    na.action = na.omit), .parallel=FALSE)
```

and call the function `fun1("cat3")`, the function will execute

```
list_of_models <- dlply(m1,.(cat1,cat3), function(X) lm(mod.form, data = X,
    na.action=na.omit), .parallel=FALSE)
```

where `cat1`, `cat2` and `cat3` are the names of categorical variables.

Thank you for your help.

Edit: As the function stands at the moment, it does not work properly because `".(cat1,arg1)"` is not "recognizable" in `dlply`. Some modifications are needed, but how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `c("cat1", arg1)` instead of `.(cat1, arg1)`.

Citing `?dlply`:

> #### Arguments
>
> `.variables`   variables to split data frame by, as quoted variables, a formula or **character vector**